# How to force elements to be in middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to show some images but I can't figure out how to move them in middle. Does anyone has any idea?

CSS

```
.cover-image{
        max-width: 300px;
        max-height: 250px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" id="covers">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <div class="cover" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <a target="_blank"><img class="cover-image" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        url: 'data.json',
        success : function(data) {
        var data = data.info;
        var covers = document.getElementById("covers");
        var blockTemplate = covers.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].cloneNode(true);
        covers.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].remove();
        data.forEach( function(obj) {
            block = blockTemplate.cloneNode(true);
            block.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute('href', obj.link);
            block.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute('src', obj.cover);
            covers.appendChild(block);
        });
        $("img").css({"vertical-align":"middle"});
    }
});
```

A demo of what is showing now is here: http://tdhtestserver.herobo.com/test/

Comment: Horizontally or vertically? Also, your source here has only one image, but the demo has six; do you you want the group of six images to be centered, or do you want the images vertically aligned to each other?

Comment: Both if is possible because my box is max 300px width and 250px height and images has different dimensions and I want to put everything in middle

Comment: `img` is an inline element. You can use `text-align: center` on the parent to plase them in the middle (horizontally). Otherwise you can make the images `display: inline-block` behaving like block elements and set them in the middle using the property `margin`.

Comment: Do you want to put all images at a time in the middle of the page?

Comment: By the way, don't put anything after the `</html>` end tag. The sc ript should go inside either the head or the body.

Comment: I want to put what is in `cover-image` in middle if is floated left or top put it in middle

Comment: the script is placed in body

Comment: Is it really necessary to put every image in an own `div` container? If so, than using the HTML5 element `figure` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi there, Your qustion is still not very clear. Though what I understood is, you want to bring images to the middle of the page. To do it horizontally, you can replace `margin: 0px;` from body tag to `margin: auto;`.

Comment: I want the images inside div to move in middle as the text. have a look on that demo site

Comment: You can achieve it easily by using table layout properties. Check this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9h3vu0ec/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a try

Is this what you want

Have to use psuedo-css

```
.cover {
border:1px solid;
height:200px;
width:200px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;}

.cover:before {    /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}


 .cover-image {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;  

}
```

This may make the question more clear.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sFM7C/298/)**

Comment: it is going in middle from left but what about from top?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align image middle-center, you can set fixed size to your `.cover` and set the `max-width` and `max-height` to the `a`. Then you can align the `a` using absolute position and css transform. Example:

```
.cover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.cover a {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried in JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7w5fw7fw/

I placed the images directly into the div container:

```
<div class="row" id="covers">
    <img src="http://sjhitsquad.net/wp-content/uploads/freshizer/3d142cc9444fe922cf69cf90e344ce5f_placeholder-920-350-c.gif">
    <img src="http://www.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/blueprint/placeholders/gif/grid/span-11-rows-15.gif">
    <img src="https://www.adspeed.com/placeholder-123x456.gif">
    <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x300?text=Advertisement">
    <img src="http://www.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/blueprint/placeholders/gif/grid/span-11-rows-15.gif">
    <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x300?text=Advertisement">
</div>
```

Wrapping every single image in a separate div doesn't appeal to me a lot. If there is such a need, than it is better to use `<figure>`, which is semantic.

And here is the CSS that places the images in the middle:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#covers {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The background color is there just to show you how wide and high the container is (as much as the whole body element). Depending on the window width the images may all appear in a single row or break into many rows.

Is this close to your searched behaviour?

Comment: have a look on @Vabis_Cool answer

Comment: He has only one image in his answer and you have 6 of them. That is why I was asking if you want them all at a time centered.

Comment: If you make a ajax call to a json file to populate that cover-image div then everything will be same

Comment: I don't get you. What will be the same?

Comment: so my JS is using cloneNode which take that cover div and multiply it for how many objects I have in json file then you code once and the result is same for all objects

Comment: That wasn't what I was asking for. Your JS is wrapping every image in an own div, which I already criticized. You can simplify your JS by just appending each image - no divs, no cloning.

Comment: That isn't what I was asking for. And your JS can be simplified by just appending the images - no divs, no cloning. The provided answer by @Vaibs_Cool shows a solution with a single image centered within a div. I assumed an undefined amount (in this particular case 6) of images centered in the middle of the page. That is what I was asking you: do you want to place all images, no matter how many there are, together in the center of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but i think you want this 
try to add this on your body

```
body {
  margin: auto !important;
}
```